# Reset form input values in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I want create a function using with i can reset value in form inputs without submit. I tried create that function in App Component (resetFormFields) and pass it on props to Form Component. It's preety simply when I want to do this onSubmit (e.target.reset()) but I got stuck when I have to do it without submit, on a different element than the form. Can I do that without adding these values to state?

App:

```
class App extends Component {

state = {
    people: [],
    formMessages: [],
    person: null
};

handleFormSubmit = e => {

    e.preventDefault();

    const form = e.target;
    const name = form.elements["name"].value;
    const username = form.elements["username"].value;

    this.addPerson(name, email);
    form.reset();
};

resetFormFields = () => {
    return;
}

render() {

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Form formSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} 
                  reset={this.resetFormFields} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Form:

```
    const Form = props => (
  <form className={classes.Form}
    id="form"
    onSubmit={props.formSubmit}>

    <input autoFocus
        id="name"
        type="text"
        defaultValue=""
        placeholder="Name..."
    />
    <input
        id="email"
        type="text"
        defaultValue=""
        placeholder="Email..."
    />
    <Button
        btnType="Submit"
        form="form"
        type='submit'>
        Submit
    </Button>
    <label onClick={props.reset}>Reset fields</label>
</form> );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your inputs controlled by passing the value you store in your `state` then you just have to reset the state values and your component value resets.

check this sample below

```
handleInputChange = (e) => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      inputs: {
      [name]: value
      }
});
```

}

your component will now look like

```
<input name='fullName' value={this.state.inputs.fullName} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
```

Your reset function will just clear the state and your input field will be empty since it's controlled via `state`

```
resetInputFields = () => {
   this.setState({ inputs: {} })
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
onHandleFormSubmit = (e) =>{  
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.reset();
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the easiest way and works. Can anyone explain why this is not the best answer and why the others that set the value using state is more legit? If not then this is so easy.

Comment: Honestly, this worked for me when the other setState wasn't working.  Thanks for sharing Abito!

Comment: I consider this to be the best answer because it resets the form without needing to use state.

Answer (score 1):

you should give set your input values based on component state, then just update the component state

```
class App extends Component {

state = {
    people: [],
    formMessages: [],
    person: null,
    name: "",
    email: "",
};

updateState = (newState) => {
    this.setState(newState);
}

handleFormSubmit = e => {

    e.preventDefault();

    this.addPerson(this.state.name, this.state.email);
    form.reset();
};

resetFormFields = () => {
    this.setState({name:"", email: ""});
}

render() {

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Form formSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}  updateState={this.updateState}
                  reset={this.resetFormFields} email={this.state.email} name={this.state.name} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

and then

```
const Form = props => (
  <form className={classes.Form}
    id="form"
    onSubmit={props.formSubmit}>

    <input autoFocus
        id="name"
        type="text"
        defaultValue=""
        value={this.props.name}
        onChange={(e) => this.props.updateState({name: e.target.value})}
        placeholder="Name..."
    />
    <input
        id="email"
        type="text"
        defaultValue=""
        value={this.props.email}
        onChange={(e) => this.props.updateState({email: e.target.value})}
        placeholder="Email..."
    />
    <Button
        btnType="Submit"
        form="form"
        type='submit'>
        Submit
    </Button>
    <label onClick={props.reset}>Reset fields</label>
</form> );
```

Comment: Indeed it may not be 'magical' like a pure reset but is more flexible and React friendly.